# jquery show div won't stop animation

Tags: jquery, hide, show, slidetoggle

I'm trying to customize a show/hide  function. On rollover of a div another div slideToggles downward and stays that way as long as the cursor is over the parent div. When the mouse leaves the area of the parent div, the secondary div should slide back up. This code does that but slides up and down multiple times on mouseenter and mouseout, when it should do it just once for each event. Any ideas? thx.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

    $('.show_hide').mouseout(function()
    {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [stop(true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before each animation, like this:

```
$(".slidingDiv").stop(true).slideToggle();
```

Use this instead and let me know if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();
  $(".show_hide").show();

  $('.show_hide').hover(
      function () {
         $(".slidingDiv").stop(true).slideToggle();
      },
      function() {
         $(".slidingDiv").stop(true).slideToggle();
      }
  );

});
```

Check the [jQuery hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks but there's still a bug. Only rollover of the title performs the function properly. The rest of the area fails as you can see. http://jsfiddle.net/ophilium/VFBQS/

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm a designer by trade so I have trouble these things.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, Mike beat me to it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698021/1933563

`$(".slidingDiv").stop(true).slideToggle();`

Comment: @75inchpianist, Rollover fast multiple times and then get your mouse cursor away. The animation will continue...

Comment: Thanks but there's still a bug. Only rollover of the title performs the function properly. The rest of the area fails as you can see. jsfiddle.net/ophilium/VFBQS